# Convert e-utils command to equivalent in Bio.Entrez (BioPython)

Tags: python-3.x, biopython

I'm having some trouble to connect each command using BioPython.

Can someone help me to transform this command line to the equivalent using BioPython?

```
esearch -db assembly -query "GCF_002514765.1" | elink -target biosample | efetch -format xml
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Esummary may solve it.

```
from Bio import Entrez

acc = "GCF_002514765.1"
search = Entrez.read(Entrez.esearch(db="assembly", term=acc))
summary = Entrez.read(Entrez.esummary(db="assembly",id=idsearch['IdList'],report="full"))
```